# Why does OpenBook Market ID show Unknown-USDC in Solscan when metadata is completed?

Tags: spl-token, metadata, serum-market

I have created an SPL token with metadata:

https://solscan.io/token/H6jYKkuRM6DX7t7keeVDm7neGW6RUQWSNw2EZub1ruhz#metadata

[image]

I can see the token image and the metadata, so everything looks okay.

But, When I go to the address holding the token and click the drop-down menu, the token is showing as an unknown token in the list.

https://solscan.io/account/H9Jx3zMvaMvtRinG4wyh2KV4U9mM6US3j4wDjnNxyuAN

[image]

Additonally, when I try to add the Market ID on Solape or Raydium it says 'Unknown Token'.

https://dex.solape.io/#/market/2i5RmZqjPrRJKRYCGkpP8yhNgtr13MEagfGdzFqU93Q9

[image]

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

anyone can create a token w/ any metadata. you could mint a very plausible looking USDC counterfeit. hence all defi apps apply some scrutiny to unvetted metadata and display them as "unknown tokens". reaching out to the maintainers can help.